# Why am I getting junk values despite using calloc()?

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation

I would like to know why the first two elements are always non-zero. I don't know how more I can describe the question, but this is not allowing me to post the question, so I'm writing this. Not sure if this will work.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 3

void printMatrix(int **m)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
            printf("%d ", m[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int **matrix;

    matrix = (int **) calloc(sizeof(int), SIZE);

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
        matrix[i] = (int *) calloc(sizeof(int), SIZE);

    printf("%s\n", "Matrix initialized.");

    printMatrix(matrix);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Matrix initialized.
1371548192 32653 0 
0 0 0 
0 0 0
```

Comment: Can you update your first call to calloc as `matrix = (int **) calloc(sizeof(int*), SIZE);` and let me know if there is any change?

Comment: Yes, it worked after I changed it to `sizeof(int *)`. I realized it will be 8 on my system as opposed to `sizeof(int)` which is 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not allocating enough memory:

```
matrix = (int **) calloc(sizeof(int), SIZE);
```

Here you're attempting to create an array of 3 `int *`, but you're only allocating space for 3 `int`.  If a pointer is larger than an `int` on your system, which it most likely is, you write past the end of the array when you create the arrays for each row.  Writing past the end of allocated memory invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Since you're creating an array of `int *`, use that for the size of each element:

```
matrix = calloc(sizeof(int *), SIZE);
```

Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc`/`realloc`/`calloc`, as that can mask a bug if you forget to `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 3):

The code uses `calloc(sizeof(int), SIZE)`, but the actual datatype in the structure is `int *`, leading to insufficient memory allocation on some systems (mine gives `int` size as 4 and `int *` size as 8).

Here's a rewrite suggestion (we'll swap size parameters in the `calloc` call per its header):

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int **matrix;

    if (!(matrix = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(*matrix)))) { 
        fprintf(stderr, "calloc failed");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i) {
         if (!(matrix[i] = calloc(SIZE, sizeof(*(matrix[i]))))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "calloc failed");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    printf("%s\n", "Matrix initialized.");
    printMatrix(matrix);
    return 0;
}
```

Here, we use `*matrix` and `*matrix[i]` instead of [hard coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) the types `int *` and `int` respectively. This can help us avoid bugs and hunting for locations to change code if we need to make type adjustments at some point.

We also check that `calloc` succeeds by testing that the pointer is non-NULL. Failing to do so can introduce difficult-to-find bugs due to undefined behavior.

Note [Do I cast the result of `malloc`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858).

Comment: `sizeof(*matrix[i])` scares me a little.  Is that `sizeof( (*matrix)[i])` or `sizeof( * (matrix[i]))`?  Certainly the rules dictate one or the other, yet `sizeof *(matrix[i])` leave no doubt to the `p = malloc(sizeof *(p) * n)` idiom.

Answer (score 2):

Reference manual describes `calloc` as:

```c
void* calloc (size_t num, size_t size);
```

So, `calloc` takes firstly `num` of elements and then `size` of a particular element

Try:

```c
matrix = (int **) calloc(SIZE, sizeof(int *));
```

Comment: Note that the issue is not the ordering of the parameters (it ends up not mattering, although it is good that you suggest to use the proper one), but the `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @Acorn I agree with you in some general way. The clue is to allocate memory for next pointer, instead of the type of values. Size of pointer depends on the system settings and then this is a reason why we have got an undefined behavior.